# Advice on Python tkinter PIL slideshow script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, macos-catalina

I am trying to run a script that seems to work for others, but not me: https://gist.github.com/terencewu/034e09f0e318c621516b

I have all the packages installed on my mac, using python3 pip, os is 10.15.7.

The only change I've made to the script is to put in a path to a folder with some pictures in it.

When I run the script, I don't get any errors, and the Python terminal prints the full correct paths, but no slideshow.  I'm using IDLE 3.9.1.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions as to how to get the script working.

Here's the code (curr_dir contains 3 jpg files):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import sys
import os

class HiddenRoot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #hackish way, essentially makes root window
        #as small as possible but still "focused"
        #enabling us to use the binding on <esc>
        self.wm_geometry("0x0+0+0")

        self.window = MySlideShow(self)
        self.window.startSlideShow()


class MySlideShow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #remove window decorations
        self.overrideredirect(True)

        #save reference to photo so that garbage collection
        #does not clear image variable in show_image()
        self.persistent_image = None
        self.imageList = []
        self.pixNum = 0

        #used to display as background image
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.getImages()

    def getImages(self):

        curr_dir = "/Users/kenpeel/Pictures/testpics/FolderA/FolderA1"

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(curr_dir):
            for f in files:
                if f.endswith(".png") or f.endswith(".jpg"):
                    img_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                    print(img_path)
                    self.imageList.append(img_path)

    def startSlideShow(self, delay=4): #delay in seconds
        myimage = self.imageList[self.pixNum]
        self.pixNum = (self.pixNum + 1) % len(self.imageList)
        self.showImage(myimage)
        #its like a callback function after n seconds (cycle through pics)
        self.after(delay*1000, self.startSlideShow)

    def showImage(self, filename):
        image = Image.open(filename)

        img_w, img_h = image.size
        scr_w, scr_h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        width, height = min(scr_w, img_w), min(scr_h, img_h)
        image.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        #set window size after scaling the original image up/down to fit screen
        #removes the border on the image
        scaled_w, scaled_h = image.size
        self.wm_geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(scaled_w,scaled_h,0,0))

        # create new image
        self.persistent_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label.configure(image=self.persistent_image)


slideShow = HiddenRoot()
slideShow.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: slideShow.destroy())  # exit on esc
slideShow.mainloop()
```

The IDLE shell prints the paths, but there are no other errors:

```
/Users/kenpeel/Pictures/testpics/FolderA/FolderA1/PICT0001.jpg
/Users/kenpeel/Pictures/testpics/FolderA/FolderA1/PICT0002.jpg
/Users/kenpeel/Pictures/testpics/FolderA/FolderA1/PICT0003.jpg
>>>
```

It seems it could be Mac OS compatability with Pillow and tkinter?

Comment: Did you pass the folder path when executing the script?  If not, it will look up images in current directory.

Comment: please provide actual code in your question. Linking to a site is not a good idea. Please read [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It works fine for me.  But why don't use the root window directly instead of using another toplevel with the root window size set to 0x0? It is not quite a good design.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for testing the script, what versions of Python and Pillow are you using?

Comment: Python 3.9.1 and Pillow 8.1.0 in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, again, @acw1668 that's very helpful.  Yes you're right, the code could be better.